# React/Redux Receive data from JSON and display/edit them

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am trying to help a friend build a React/Redux app where it will get some data from a JSON file and diplay them and be able to edit them.

As we are both new to this and the deadline is pretty close I was wondering if there is anyone who can enlight us on how to do it.

I tried a couple of tutorials like these

1. [Tutorial 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7-gMz1pP5NE)
2. [Tutorial 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9CPmtIeapMw)

but they weren't too much help as they are either outdated or not what we are looking for.

I apologize if this is not the place to ask this but this project has to be done.

We are either looking someone to help us to it or send us like good examples on how to do it.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

For fetching data in Redux, you need to write a Redux middleware or use middleware wrapper like `redux-saga` or `redux-observable`, etc. I recommend you to use `redux-observable`. Take a look at [this repo](https://github.com/zamotany/redux-observable-todo-mvc) for how to build a todo app using React and Redux Observable.

About Redux middleware, I suggest you to read [this article](https://medium.com/@jacobp100/you-arent-using-redux-middleware-enough-94ffe991e6).